# Change line style circle segment Venn diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

I have this Venn diagram:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles

venn2(subsets = (30, 10, 5), set_labels = ('Group A', 'Group B'), set_colors=('r', 'g'), alpha = 0.5);
venn2_circles(subsets = (30, 10, 5));
```

[image]

Is it possible to change the line style to dashed of just the circle segments where Group A and B overlap (i.e. the lines around the brown area)?

Comment: I don't know `matplotlib` well, but have found an online resource that shows an example of this. [The resource is here.](https://www.programmersought.com/article/22117010728/#%E4%B8%AA%E6%80%A7%E5%8C%96%E8%AE%BE%E7%BD%AE%E5%9B%BE%E4%B8%AD7%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E6%AF%8F%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86) When you have solved your problem please remember to post the solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include another method for adding this line style, though it is quite involved.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to give such a comprehensive answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1

By setting the `edgecolor` on each of the patches in the venn diagram (`A`, `B`, and `C`) we can see that the paths overlap around the overlapping section.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles

for char in "ABC":
    v = venn2(
        subsets=(30, 10, 5),
        set_labels=("Group A", "Group B"),
        set_colors=("r", "g"),
        alpha=0.5,
    )
    overlap = v.get_patch_by_id(char)
    overlap.set_edgecolor("black")
    overlap.set_alpha(1)
    overlap.set_ls("dashed")
    overlap.set_lw(1.5)
    plt.show()
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: A] | [image: B] | [image: C] |

But, by using a contrasting colour we can outline the overlap. The downside to this method is that we loose the `alpha` on the overlap.

```py
# plot venn
v = venn2(
    subsets=(30, 10, 5),
    set_labels=("Group A", "Group B"),
    set_colors=("r", "g"),
    alpha=0.5,
)
# add circles
c = venn2_circles(subsets=(30, 10, 5), linewidth=2, color="black")

overlap = v.get_patch_by_id("C")  # get the overlap
overlap.set_edgecolor("white")    # set the edgecolor
overlap.set_alpha(1)              # set the alpha to 1 otherwise 
                                  #   we can't see the line
overlap.set_linestyle("dashed")   # set a dashed line
overlap.set_linewidth(2)          # set same linewidth as the circles
overlap.set_zorder(2)             # bump overlap up a level so we can 
                                  #   see the line
```

[image: overlapped section with dashed edge]

---

## Option 2

This method is completely untested outside of this problem As far as I can tell it should work for most 2-circle venn diagrams.

This one is a bit more involved, but it allows us to seamlessly add dashed lines around the overlap without affecting the `alpha`.
It requires that we import a function from a private module in `matplotlib_venn`, `circle_circle_intersection` which we will use to create [`matplotlib.patches.Arc`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html)s.

These arcs will replace the circles drawn by `matplotlib_venn`.

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
from matplotlib_venn._math import circle_circle_intersection

# Create `v` and `c` as in the previous example

# Get the current ax
ax = plt.gca()
# Get the intersections of the circles
(P2x, P2y), (P3x, P3y) = circle_circle_intersection(
    c[0].center, c[0].radius, c[1].center, c[1].radius
)

# Iterate through the circles matplotlib_venn added
for _c in c:
    # remove the circle
    _c.set_visible(False)
    # get the center or the circle and the angle at the center (theta)
    P1x, P1y = _c.center
    theta = math.degrees(
        math.atan2(P3y - P1y, P3x - P1x) - math.atan2(P2y - P1y, P2x - P1x)
    )
    # Add the Arcs
    ax.add_patch(
        Arc(
            xy=_c.center,
            width=_c.radius * 2,
            height=_c.radius * 2,
            linewidth=2,
            color="black",
            angle=theta / 2 if theta < 180 else theta / -2,
            theta2=360 - theta if theta < 180 else theta,
        )
    )
    ax.add_patch(
        Arc(
            xy=_c.center,
            width=_c.radius * 2,
            height=_c.radius * 2,
            linewidth=2,
            color="black",
            linestyle="dashed",
            angle=theta / 2 if theta > 180 else theta / -2,
            theta2=360 - theta if theta > 180 else theta,
        )
    )
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image: Overlapping venn diagram with different edges and preserved alpha]